# VLOOKUP is mapping some values correctly, but is not consistent --> randomly returns "#N/A

Tags: excel, vlookup

[Example: See 1> where I have selected "colleges & Universities" --> "Education" (which is correct), but then notice how 3 rows down VLOOKUP returns "#N/A" for the same scenario...why is this?[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qidNQ.png)

See 2> I am pulling the table_array from another sheet in the same workbook
[image of table_array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zL62m.png)

Comment: Here's the formula I used: =VLOOKUP('data mapping'!C2&"",mapping!A1:B46,2)

Comment: Try `=VLOOKUP('data mapping'!C2&"", mapping!A:B, 2, FALSE)`

Comment: @Jeeped That worked -- thank you! I have another question --> The cells with no industry [blank values] in column "Mapped Industry" by default show "#N/A", but I need them to remain blank. --> What changes do I need to make to my formula to show that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as a standard formula,

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP('data mapping'!C2&"", mapping!A:B, 2, FALSE), "")
```

A [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) requires FALSE on unsorted data. While the data you showed appeared sorted, there must be unsorted data further down.

The [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) has been around since xl2007 and drastically reduces the formula needed for error control over `IF(ISERROR(...`.

Answer (score 0):

You used relative referencing in setting the range of your VLOOKUP. Try using an absolute reference instead:

```
=VLOOKUP('data mapping'!C2&"",mapping!$A$1:$B$46,2)
```

Then simply copy down.